# How to make RTC sysfs available to user

Tags: permissions, armbian

<s>In Armbian, I've been able to make the GPIO sysfs available for users in the `gpio` group using the unstructions on [this first post](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/1851-rfc-make-armbian-more-iot-friendly/) and this works. This worked successfully for my unprivileged user.</s>

Now I'm trying to do the same for the RTC sysfs without luck.

What I've tried are most steps from [this post](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=2233) up to where they're editing the rules.d file: there's no `/sys/devices/soc.0` on my device. Instead I added under he `gpio*` command list, this line:

```
chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/rtc && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/rtc;\
```

This doesn't seem to work. Even if I execute these commands manually and confirm the rtc folder tree is of root:gpio with 770 permissions, it still doesn't work (permission denied from the unprivileged user).

```
$ cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc1/since_epoch # this works!
$ echo 10 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc1/since_epoch # permission denied
```

Excuse me, I just realized the sysfs of the RTC seems to be read-only. Now my question shifts to, how can I set the HW time via sysfs? (Alternatively, how can I set the HW time at all from userspace?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is an answer to my last-resort question "how can I set the HW time at all from userspace?"

Recently I learned about `sudoers`, which seems to be the universal solution for everything related to defeating su rights.

Run `visudo` as root. This is a shortcut to editing `sudoers`. Don't worry, it won't start `vi`, but your default editor (unless that *is* `vi`). Using this instead of manually editing `/etc/sudoers` causes the changes to be applied upon closing, and it gives warnings and errors if necessary.

I'm not yet a sudoers wizard (the man page is like 50 pages long) but I ended up adding this to the end:

```
Cmnd_Alias TIMEDATE=/usr/bin/timedatectl
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: TIMEDATE
```

The using an alias instead of directly specifying the command allows you to use random command line arguments.

Then user `pi` can execute `sudo timedatectl` without being asked for a password. (note: `sudo` is still required.)